User Session Showing in w and who Command But TTY Not Found
On one of my Gentoo linux servers I noticed a user session that seems to be lingering. When I run the w command, it shows the following output:
w
22:21:01 up 80 days,  1:15,  3 users,  load average: 0.21, 0.31, 0.38
USER     TTY        LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT
root     pts/0     21:09    3.00s  0.03s  0.01s sshd: root [priv]         
root     pts/1     22:19    3.00s  0.04s  0.01s sudo su -
joe      pts/3     Wed09    0.00s  0.00s  0.06s sudo su - application_user

The user joe appears to be logged in on pts/3 since Wednesday at 09:00. However, when I run ps -ft pts/3, I get the following:
ps -ft pts/3
error: TTY could not be found

I checked user's processes with ps -u joe no current processes are linked with this user.
ps -e -o pid,tty,user,cmd --sort=tty and not processes are run under pts/3, I see only my pts/0 and pts/1 in the list.
Listed Open Files using lsof -u joe, also no results.
This is the /dev/pts
ls -l /dev/pts
total 0
crw--w---- 1 root   tty  136, 0 Jun 30 22:41 0
crw--w---- 1 root   tty  136, 1 Jun 30 22:41 1
c--------- 1 root   root   5, 2 Apr 11 21:06 ptmx

None of these steps show any processes or sessions associated with joe or pts/3.
Upon further investigation (based on w command) I determined that joe switched to application_user (application account used to start the service) and then from that account he connected via ssh to another server. At one moment joe disconnected (my guess is that his VPN stopped since there is time limit for each connection) but processes he started did not completely stop.
Listing all processes "sudo su - application_user"
ps -ef | grep "sudo su - application_user"  (this is the command listed as last command by user joe in output of w)

root     26881     1  0 Jun26 ?        00:00:00 sudo su - application_user
root     26989 26881  0 Jun26 ?        00:00:00 sudo su - application_user
root     26990 26989  0 Jun26 ?        00:00:00 su - application_user

ps -ef | grep 26990
root     26990 26989  0 Jun26 ?        00:00:00 su - application_user
application_user  26992 26990  0 Jun26 ?        00:00:00 -bash

ps -ef | grep 26992
application_user  26992 26990  0 Jun26 ?        00:00:00 -bash
application_user  30391 26992  0 Jun26 ?        00:00:00 ssh foo@remote_server_02

If I kill this processes (ssh, bash...) user joe will be logged out.
My question: Is there a better (more deterministic) way of determining what processes are started by joe? My procedure above relies on searching the last command started by joe, but there is no direct link (not by username or pts/3) between joe and first "sudo su - application_user" that is started by root under the parent process ID 1.
And second question is why is this happening, why does the w and who command show joe as logged in if there are no processes or pts used by it?


Is there a better (more deterministic) way of determining what processes are started by joe?

Search for processes which have /proc/##/loginuid set to that user's UID. This needs to be 1) enabled in the kernel as CONFIG_AUDITSYSCALL and 2) updated at login time by pam_loginuid.so.
Another, slightly less robust approach (as root may escape it and therefore any user with sudo rights may escape it as well) is to look at the processes within the user's cgroup. This needs the system to be running some software which creates those per-user cgroups – systemd-logind is one such example, I believe there are others for non-systemd distros such as elogind or cgmanager; all of those similarly rely on a PAM module to activate them when the user logs in.
In the case of systemd, loginctl user-status foo or systemctl status user-123.slice would show a nice process tree; otherwise /proc/##/cgroup is the starting point.
(Unfortunately, systemd also introduces a nice way to escape the 'loginuid' tracking by simply asking systemd to start a temporary service, for which it has several commands... The same was already possible for root to achieve without systemd but would've needed a bit more invasive configuration.)

And second question is why is this happening, why does the w and who command show joe as logged in if there are no processes or pts used by it?

While that shouldn't happen when the network connection goes away, entries in /run/utmp may end up stale if the process that has added an entry gets killed before it has a chance to remove it at the end. There is no central facility that would reliably manage utmp entries on behalf of login processes such as sshd, like there is for loginctl for example.
